# REFInd not showing up

Tags: dual-boot, refind

I’m trying to dual-boot Ubuntu with Windows 10, but I don’t have access to a USB or disc so I have to install without installation media. To do that, I made a 5GB partition to mimic a USB drive. I’ll just explain everything here:

- I accidentally messed up installing rEFInd once before, my computer ran out of battery while I was in the process . But I tried again and I used this video https://youtu.be/h48BWtm1NCU to install rEFInd, and it installed perfectly.
- I made a new 5GB Partition and extracted all the Ubuntu ISO Files onto the new partition.
- I restarted my computer, but the rEFInd menu didn’t show up, it just asked me to pick between Windows 10 and Unetbootin - oh crap! I used Unetbootin a long time ago and forgot to get rid of it! I booted into windows 10, uninstalled Unetbootin and restarted my computer.
- well, now, the rEFInd menu WILL NOT SHOW UP, it just goes straight to windows.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using [EasyUEFI](https://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) to check if it shows rEFInd there?
If not just try following the instructions [here](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#windows) and reinstall rEFInd. 
If that still doesn't work try switching between Legacy BIOS and UEFI bios.
And finally if that still doesn't work, I think the fastest solution would be just installing Ubuntu (or running it in live mode if it's already installed) using a USB and installing rEFInd from there.

I hope that helps.